# UWP Background Tasks unregistered after store update

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp

Do my Windows 10 App Backgroundtasks unregister while you update the app with the store?
Will the app deinstall and install or do I have to unregister my backgroundtask manual if I made a change in the backgroundtask registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do my Windows 10 App Backgroundtasks unregister while you update the
>   app with the store?

No, according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.backgroundtaskcancellationreason), when an app gets updated, only running background tasks get canceled, not unregistered:

> The background task was canceled because the application was updated.

You shouldn't need to register your background tasks again, however, it's not a bad practice to check for background tasks in the app startup and register any tasks that are not already registered. You can get list of the registered background tasks from the [BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br224787) property.

However, if you want a background task with different properties/conditions, you need to unregister the old one and register the new one again, since you need a different background task.